# How to iterate over multiline text in text box in php?

Tags: php, html, loops, iteration

What I am trying to do is I want to write a little helper application for myself, which will convert list of coordinates into list of coordinates in bb code, like so:

This is what user will input:

```
123|456
```

And the output will be:

```
1. [coord]123|456[/coord]
```

So basically I need something that will allow me to store the multiline text as a php variable, and then to iterate over that variable changing each line like in the example above.

Please help :)

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: A php variable doesn't real care if the text is multiline or not. I guess this could be fixed with a find and replace function over a regexp that understand your coords.

Comment: I haven't tried to do anything codewise, I tried researching appropiate functions to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create simple form:

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="multilineData"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Than you can process submitted form:

```
<?php
$output = '';
$num = 1;
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['multilineData']) as $row) {
    $output .= "$num. [coord]$row[/coord]<br>";
    $num++;
}
echo $output;
```